# Visual studio Error C2784

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with simple code that working with g++ compiler on Linux but I got many Errors with Visual studio professional 2012 on Windows.

The code:

```
string tmp = *path;
  if(tmp.length() == 0) 
    *path = Name_;
  else
    *path = Name_ + '.' + tmp;
```

The Error:

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr> std::operator +(_String_iterator<_Mystr>::difference_type,std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>' from 'char'
```

The program points me to + operator. 
Also my includes are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

In addition I have a problems with cout <<.  The operator << does not recognized by Visual studio although iostream included.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <string>` instead of `string.h` (the latter declares C string functions like `strstr`, `strcmp`, etc.)

If your operand is a `std::string`, including `<string>` will probably also fix the problem with `<<` not being recognized.

Edit: as an aside, `if (tmp.empty())` is generally preferred over `if(tmp.length() == 0)`.